# sshpass in Java gives error: /bin/sh: sshpass: command not found

Tags: java, shell

I'm trying to execute a simple sshpass command in java:

```
String command = "sshpass -p password ssh user@host 'echo test' ";

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", command);
pb.inheritIO();
Process process = pb.start();
process.waitFor();
```

But the execution of command fails printing the following error on the console:

```
/bin/sh: sshpass: command not found
```

If I execute the command in the Terminal od my Mac OS, the command runs perfectly. (already installed sshpass via brew).

How to execute the command also in java?

Comment: Give the full path to sshpass.

Comment: That was the trick! You're a genius! :D

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, this is the right command (for Mac):

```
String command = "/usr/local/bin/sshpass -p password ssh user@host 'echo test' ";
```

You can find the right path executing the following command:

```
$ which sshpass
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a Unix thing, not Java. There are two things here:

- By not giving the absolute path to `sshpass`, you rely on the shell to find it in `$PATH`
- You explicitly start a *new* shell, which - as it is non-interactive - does not load all the configuration files your interactive shell did.  If the adding of `/usr/local/bin` to `$PATH` is not placed in an appropriate configuration file it will not be executed.  Full details available in the shell manual page.

By giving the absolute path you circumvent the lookup mechanism!

Comment: thanks for your suggests, I'll think about it for a better mechanism. However using /usr/local/bin/sshpass it works in Java, it's enough for my scope!

Comment: Absolute path is the best approach.  I am just explaining why it didn't work for you.